# document.getElementByID is replacing javascript with html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have `HTML` a h2 with id of "**containerTitle**" like this:

```
 <h2 id = "containerTitle"> Container Placeholder</h2>
```

and in my JavaScript I am trying to replace the text associated with this id like this:

```
document.getElementById("containerTitle").innerHTML = "NewText";
```

however, it breaks. When I look at the source of the new HTML in browser, the line that I wrote with `getElementById` is changed to this:

```
<h2 id = "containerTitle"> Container Placeholder</h2>
```

and it breaks my JavaScript. Why would this line replace my JavaScript with the HTML? Getting the element by ID has been working for everything else. Please help! I'm primarily a C# programmer, but am helping with an HTML project.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Case Scenario</title>
        <style>
            table tr td
            {
                border:1px solid #222;
                padding: 0.5em;
                padding-top: 0; 
            }
            table
            {
                border-spacing: 0;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            body
            {
                background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
                font-family: Georgia, Charcoal, serif;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            img
            {
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>     
    </head>
   <body>
        <h1 id = "caseTitle"> Case Scenario 1</h1>
        <h2 id = "containerTitle"> Container Placeholder</h2>
        <div style="border-right:1px solid #222; float:left; display:inline-
   block; width:45%; overflow-y:scroll; max-height:600px; padding:1%">
          <div id="caseS" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; 
   margin-left:1%; margin-top:1%"></div>
            <img id="imgS" src="" style="">
            <table id="tableS" style="margin-left:10%; margin-bottom:2%;
       text-align:center">
            <p id="containerDescription"> Container Description   placeholder</p>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:4px; display:inline-block; max-width:50%;   overflow-y:scroll; max-height:600px; padding:1%;">
            <div id="runningCount">Score: 0</div>
            <h2 id="titleQ">Question 1</h2>
            <div id="askingQ"></div>
            <br>
            <form id="formQ">

            </form>
            <input type="button" onClick="testQ()" value="Check Answer"  id="checkQ">
            <br>
            <b id="alertQ" style="margin-top:0; padding-top:0; width:30%"></b>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            var CaseCount = 0;
            var CaseContainerCount = 0;
            var CaseContainerQuestionCount = 0;
            var CaseContainerAnswerCount = 0;
            var QuestionCount = 1;
            var currentAnswerCollection = "Case" + CaseCount + "Container" + CaseContainerCount + "Question" + CaseContainerQuestionCount + "Answers";
            var newHTML = "";
            var radioArray = new Array();
            var answerCount = 0;
            var checkedAnswerCount = 0;


            //document.write(currentAnswerCollection.length);               
            setup();             

            function setup()
            {

                    for(var j = 0; j < AnswersArray[0].length; j++)
                    {

                        newHTML += "<span id=\"a_a"+ j + "\"></span><input type=\"radio\" name=\"grouping\" id=\"a" + j + "0\" value=\"" + j + "\"><span onclick=\"easyRadio('a" + j + "')\" ontouchstart\"easyRadio('a" + j + "')\">" + AnswersArray[answerCount][j].answerText + "</span><br><br>";           

                    }

                //} 
                //document.getElementById("askingQ").innerHTML = Case0Container0Questions[0];
                document.getElementById("askingQ").innerHTML = QuestionsArray[CaseContainerCount][CaseContainerQuestionCount];
                document.getElementById("formQ").innerHTML = newHTML;
                //answerCount++;
                //document.write(AnswersArray[0][0].answerText);
            }

            function testQ()
            {

                radioArray = document.getElementsByName("grouping");
                for(var i = 0; i < radioArray.length; i++)
                {

                                            //document.write(i);
                    if(radioArray[i].checked)
                    {
                        if(AnswersArray[answerCount][i].isCorrect == "True")
                        {
                            document.getElementById("a_a" + i).innerHTML = "<img src='img/right.png' class='mark'>";
                            checkedAnswerCount++;
                            MarkRightAnswer();                              
                            break;                          
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(checkedAnswerCount < (radioArray.length - 2))
                            {
                                document.getElementById("a_a" + i).innerHTML = "<img src='img/wrong.png' class='mark'>";
                                //console.log(checkedAnswerCount);
                                checkedAnswerCount++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                document.getElementById("a_a" + i).innerHTML = "<img src='img/wrong.png' class='mark'>";
                                MarkRightAnswer();
                            }
                            break;                          
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            function MarkRightAnswer()
            {
                checkedAnswerCount = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i < AnswersArray[answerCount].length; i++)
                {
                    if(AnswersArray[answerCount][i].isCorrect == "True")
                    {
                        document.getElementById("a_a" + i).innerHTML = "<img src='img/right.png' class='mark'>";
                        //change button for next question                           
                        document.getElementById("checkQ").setAttribute("value","Next!");    
                        document.getElementById("checkQ").setAttribute("onclick","NextQuestion()");                     

                    }

                }
            }

            function NextQuestion()
            {
                CaseContainerQuestionCount++;
                answerCount++;
                QuestionCount++;                    
                newHTML = "";                   
                    for(var j = 0; j < AnswersArray[0].length; j++)
                    {   
                        newHTML += "<span id=\"a_a"+ j + "\"></span><input type=\"radio\" name=\"grouping\" id=\"a" + j + "0\" value=\"" + j + "\"><span onclick=\"easyRadio('a" + j + "')\" ontouchstart\"easyRadio('a" + j + "')\">" + AnswersArray[answerCount][j].answerText + "</span><br><br>";           

                    }                   
                    //check length of containerQuestion array. If at end of array, go to next container 

                    if(CaseContainerQuestionCount >= QuestionsArray[CaseContainerCount].length)
                    {
                        CaseContainerCount++;
                        CaseContainerQuestionCount = 0; 
                        console.log( QuestionsArray[CaseContainerCount].length);                        
                    }

                document.getElementById("containerTitle").innerHTML = "BOOOOOYAAA";
                document.getElementById("askingQ").innerHTML = QuestionsArray[CaseContainerCount][CaseContainerQuestionCount];  
                document.getElementById("formQ").innerHTML = newHTML;
                document.getElementById("titleQ").innerHTML = "Question " + QuestionCount;
                document.getElementById("checkQ").setAttribute("value","Check Answer"); 
                document.getElementById("checkQ").setAttribute("onclick","testQ()");                    
            }



        </script>
```

Comment: Include the entire relevant DOM and JS. Better yet, a running jsfiddle/etc example.

Comment: Post your code that relates to this issue

Comment: Maybe some more code because right now the code provided works for me.

Comment: I think you should use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property instead of `innerHtml`

Comment: This makes no sense at all, unless the script tag is inside an element with the same iD, that wouldn't happen.

Comment: @adeneo is absolutely correct. It makes no sense at all...

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: You've got other issues because the code you show above works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/0kfxygrp/

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code. [**If I do exactly what you're saying in JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tps77kLe/), I'm getting the expected result `<h2 id="containerTitle">NewText</h2>`.

Comment: Please consider providing your code... otherwise the problem is not understandable

Comment: Would having the script in my body make this happen? I want to post all the code, but it is way too long to post.

Comment: At top:
<body>
     <h1 id = "caseTitle"> Case Scenario 1</h1>
        <h2 id = "containerTitle"> Container Placeholder</h2>
        <div style="border-right:1px solid #222; float:left; display:inline-block; width:45%; overflow-y:scroll; max-height:600px; padding:1%">
    <div id="caseS" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin-left:1%; margin-top:1%"></div>
   <img id="imgS" src="" style="">
   <table id="tableS" style="margin-left:10%; margin-bottom:2%; text-align:center">
            <p id="containerDescription"> Container Description placeholder</p>
   </table>
  </div>

Comment: Then I call a function in my script that changes get the elemen by ID.

Comment: Even when I comment out this part like this:
    //document.getElementById("containerTitle").innerHTML = "New Text";

it still replaces the javascript with HTML.

This is embedded in a function in the script.

Comment: @promark Have you tried Alexander Popov's suggestion of using textContent instead  of innerHTML?

Comment: How are you "looking at the source?" Right click->View Source? Or the developer tools?

Comment: Yup. Just tried using textContent. Same result.
@JosiahKeller, I am looking at developer tools using chrome.

Comment: I probably wouldn't worry about what the dev tools are saying about a <script> tag, then.  Is there a console error?

Comment: I just updated with the source html file. I actually use a C# program to change add variables in and resave this, so if you don't see some of the variables that I'm using later, no biggie. they are there in the final file. Everything was working until I added the getelementByID code line in the NextQuestion function. and I do close the body and htnl after it. for some reason that didn;t copy over.

Comment: `innerText` is an alternative, syntax is the same as `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

There will be duplication.

Please check that you are using the 'containerTitle' id anywhere in the page.
If you are using same id for multiple DOMs it wont work

Comment: Thanks, but that is the only place where I'm using that ID.